# How to prove cooperation from behavioural sequences

Tags: r, sequence-analysis

***Situation:*** Two birds (male and female) protect their eggs in nest against an intruder. Each bird can use either attack or threat for protection, and be either present or absent. There is a pattern emerging from data that behaviour may be complementary - male attacks while female use threat display and vice versa.

My question is: **How to statistically prove such cooperation?**
Or can anybody know some behavioural study which deals with similar analysis? Vast majority of sequential analyses I found are focused on DNA.

[image]

Here I provide some **dummy data**, but my original dataset is composed from dozens of pairs which were recorded exactly 10 minutes while defending their nest. Behavioural sequence of every bird is therefore 600 states long (each second has state). **These shorter data should contain pattern similar to whole dataset.**

```
male_seq <- rep(c("absent","present","attack","threat","present","attack",
                  "threat","present","attack","absent"),
                  times = c(3,4,8,2,6,3,2,6,2,1))

female_seq <- rep(c("absent","present","threat","present","threat","present",
                    "threat","attack","present","threat","attack","present",
                    "attack","threat","absent"),
                  times = c(2,6,2,1,2,1,1,3,5,3,1,3,3,2,2))
```

Comment: (+1) for beautifully illustrated, well-formed, and interesting question!

Comment: How do actual intrusions enter into this? Does each sequence correspond to contiguous 10-minute intervals, or only to intervals where there is an intruder? Does "absent" mean absent from the nest, or absent from the area when an intrusion occurred?

Comment: Hi @Wayne! Intruder is present from the beginning to the end (dummy puppet of predator on a stick was presented to nesting birds for 10 minutes). Absent means absent from the nesting area - sometimes parents just run away (sometimes returned after several minutes).

Comment: OK, so each string of squares includes the entire intrusion, and each adjacent square describes an contiguous 10-minute period. Good. Now, can you clarify what you mean by "cooperation"? Do you mean different roles (threaten versus attack), or do you mean sharing guard duty (absent/present versus threat/attack)?

Comment: By cooperation I mean "when male is attacking, the female make threats", and I would like to test this hypothesis against an alternative: "when male is attacking, the female do not prefer make threats" (in other words, behaviour of female is independent of male behaviour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I post second answer since your last comment

> By cooperation I mean "when male is attacking, the female make
>   threats", and I would like to test this hypothesis against an
>   alternative: "when male is attacking, the female do not prefer make
>   threats" (in other words, behaviour of female is independent of male
>   behaviour).

is a game-changer. It seems that the problem can be approach from totally different perspective. First, you are interested *only* in part of your sample when males are attacking. Second, you are interested if in such cases females make treats more often than we would expect if they made them randomly. To test such hypothesis we can use a permutation test: randomly shuffle either `male_seq` or `female_seq` (it doesn't matter) and then count cases where `male_seq == "attack"` and `female_seq == "treat"` to obtain null distribution. Next, compare count obtained from your data to counts in the null distribution to obtain $p$-value.

```
prmfun <- function() {
  sum(female_seq[sample(male_seq) == "attack"] == "threat")
}

mean(replicate(1e5, prmfun()) >= sum(female_seq[male_seq == "attack"] == "threat"))
## [1] 5e-05
```

You can define your test statistic differently, based on how do you define females' "preference". Permutation test in this case is a direct interpretation of your $H_0$: "behaviour of female is independent of male behaviour", that leads to: "female behaviour is random given male behaviour", so the behaviours are be randomly shuffled under $H_0$.

Moreover, even if you assumed that the behaviours appear in clusters of the same behaviour repeated for some period of time, with permutation test you can shuffle whole clusters:

```
female_rle <- rle(female_seq)
n_rle <- length(female_rle$values)

prmfun2 <- function() {
  ord <- sample(n_rle)
  sim_female_seq <- rep(female_rle$values[ord], female_rle$lengths[ord])
  sum(sim_female_seq[male_seq == "attack"] == "threat")
}

mean(replicate(1e5, prmfun2()) >= sum(female_seq[male_seq == "attack"] == "threat"))
## [1] 0.00257
```

In either of the cases, the co-operation patterns in the data you provided seem to be far from random. Notice that in both cases we ignore the autocorrelated nature of this data, we are rather asking: if we picked random point in time when male was attacking, would female be less or more likely to make treats at the same time?

Since you seem to be talking about causality ("when ... then"), while conducting permutation test you may be interested in comparing males behaviour in $t-1$ time to females behaviour at $t$ time (what was females' "reaction" to males behaviour?), but this is something that you have to ask yourself. Permutation tests are flexible and can be easily adapted to the kind of problems you seem to be describing.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of your data in terms of bivariate Markov chain. You have two different variables $X$ for females and $Y$ for males, that describe stochastic process of changes in $X$ and $Y$ at time $t$ to one of four different states. Let's denote by $X_{t-1,i} \rightarrow X_{t,j}$ transition for $X$ from $t-1$ to $t$ time, from $i$-th to $j$-th state. In this case, transition in time to another state is conditional on previous state in $X$ *and* in $Y$:

$$ \Pr( X_{t-1,i} \rightarrow X_{t,j} ) = \Pr(X_{t,j} | X_{t-1,i},Y_{t-1,k}) \\
   \Pr( Y_{t-1,h} \rightarrow Y_{t,k} ) = \Pr(Y_{t,h} | Y_{t-1,k},X_{t-1,i})$$

Transition probabilities can be easily calculated by counting transition histories and normalizing the probabilities afterwards:

```
states <- c("absent", "present", "attack", "threat")
# data is stored in 3-dimensional array, initialized with
# a very small "default" non-zero count to avoid zeros.
female_counts <- male_counts <- array(1e-16, c(4,4,4), list(states, states, states))
n <- length(male_seq)

for (i in 1:n) {
  male_counts[female_seq[i-1], male_seq[i-1], male_seq[i]] <- male_counts[female_seq[i-1], male_seq[i-1], male_seq[i]] + 1
  female_counts[male_seq[i-1], female_seq[i-1], female_seq[i]] <- female_counts[male_seq[i-1], female_seq[i-1], female_seq[i]] + 1
}

male_counts/sum(male_counts)
female_counts/sum(female_counts)
```

It can be also easyly simulated using marginal probabilities:

```
male_sim <- female_sim <- "absent"

for (i in 2:nsim) {
  male_sim[i] <- sample(states, 1, prob = male_counts[female_sim[i-1], male_sim[i-1], ])
  female_sim[i] <- sample(states, 1, prob = female_counts[male_sim[i-1], female_sim[i-1], ])
}
```

Result of such simulation is plotted below.

[image]

Moreover, it can be used to make one-step-ahead predictions:

```
male_pred <- female_pred <- NULL

for (i in 2:n) {
  curr_m <- male_counts[female_seq[i-1], male_seq[i-1], ]
  curr_f <- female_counts[male_seq[i-1], female_seq[i-1], ]
  male_pred[i] <- sample(names(curr_m)[curr_m == max(curr_m)], 1)
  female_pred[i] <- sample(names(curr_f)[curr_f == max(curr_f)], 1)
}
```

with 69-86% accuracy on the data you provided:

```
> mean(male_seq == male_pred, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 0.8611111
> mean(female_seq == female_pred, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 0.6944444
```

If the transitions occurred randomly, the transition probabilities would follow discrete uniform distribution. This is not a *proof*, but can serve as a way of thinking about your data using a simple model.

Comment: It seems you're assuming that the alternative to cooperation is some kind of random response. I could see that the alternative is an unccordinated response, which might be preprogrammed. For instance, a bird flies in circles. So, when a partner is dealing with the intruder the circle is larger. So they deal with the intruder one after another, without cooperation per se, but waiting until one is finished.

Comment: @Aksakal but the question is about interactions and what you are describing *is* a kind of interaction. (I do not argue that this simplistic model is correct.)

Comment: I agree, that OP is not clear whether he's looking for any kind of regular pattern or specifically "cooperation". I'd argue that when three birds are flying in the same space, there's got to be some kind of a pattern of behavior emerging. I think that "cooperation" entails more then just a pattern. Otherwise, you could say that it's three way cooperation, with intruder also cooperating in some sense.

Comment: @Aksakal you could be right, but if this data consists only of the four states observed in time, then the kind of simplistic model I proposed can serve as a starting point.